# Como uso una API rest para pasar datos de un formulario a un grafico en pyhton?

Tags: html, python, formularios

[image: Este es mi formulario]

Mi objetivo final es llenar los campos del formulario y estos se pasen al grafico, hay alguna manera de que estos capturen los datos desde el formulario y pasen al grafico escrito en Python para que después este se visualice, no necesito ninguna conexion a una base de datos o algo mas complejo si no que me muestre los datos ingresados en forma de grafico de lineas.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Formulario de Acceso </title>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
  scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Videojuegos & Desarrollo">
    <meta name="description" content="Muestra de un formulario de 
    acceso en HTML y CSS">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Formulario Acceso, ">
      <link href=https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
   family=Nunito&display=swap rel="stylesheet">
     <link href=https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
   family=Overpass&display=swap rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href=https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css />
    <script defer src=https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js> 
   </script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">  
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        <div id="central">
            <div id="login">
                <div class="titulo">Bienvenido</div>
                <form class="informacion" action="/result" 
  method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="Tasa de cambio" 
  placeholder="Tasa de cambio" required>    
                    <input type="text" name="Tasa de cambio" 
   placeholder="Ingresar VAR" required>    
                    <input type="text" name="Tasa de cambio" 
  placeholder="Ingresar cambio unitario" required>    
                    <button type="submit" title="Ingresar" 
  name="Ingresar">INGRESAR</button>
                    <py-script stc="prueba.py"></py-script>
                    <div id="grafico"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Este codigo esta en el lenguaje de python, principalmente muestra un grafico de lineas con unos parametros que se ingresan por consola, pero mi idea es que esos parametros sean ingresados desde un formulario en html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

fecha = datetime.strftime(now.date(), '%d/%m/%Y')
hora = input("Ingrese la hora: ")
usd = float(input("Ingresar valor del tipo de cambio: "))
var = float(input("Favor ingresar Var del día (%): "))
 diccionario = {'Fecha': fecha, 'Hora': hora, 'USD': usd}

df  = pd.read_csv("tipo_cambio.csv")
df = df.append(diccionario, ignore_index=True)

alerta1 = var*0.25
alerta2 = var*0.50
alerta3 = var*0.75

df_hoy = df[df['Fecha'] == fecha]
x = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) * (1+var/100) - float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2])
y = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) - float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) * (1-var/100)
z = max(x,y)
w = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) + z
v = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) - z

df_hoy = df_hoy.assign(high = w, low = v)
a = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) * (1+alerta1/100) - float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2])

b = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) - float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) * (1-alerta1/100)

c = max(a,b)

d = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) + c

e = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) - c



df_hoy = df_hoy.assign(high1 = d, low1 = e)



f = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) * (1+alerta2/100) - float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2])

g = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) - float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) * (1-alerta2/100)

h = max(f,g)

i = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) + h

j = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) - h



df_hoy = df_hoy.assign(high2 = i, low2 = j)



k = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) * (1+alerta3/100) - float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2])

l = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) - float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) * (1-alerta3/100)

m = max(k,l)

n = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) + m

o = float(df_hoy.iloc[0,2]) - m



df_hoy = df_hoy.assign(high3 = n, low3 = o)



 fig, ax = plt.subplots()

 ax.plot(df_hoy["Hora"], df_hoy["USD"], marker = ".", color = "b")

 ax.plot(df_hoy["Hora"], df_hoy["low"], linestyle = "--", color = "r")

  ax.plot(df_hoy["Hora"], df_hoy["high"], linestyle = "--", color = "r")

ax.plot(df_hoy["Hora"], df_hoy["low1"], linestyle = "--", color = "g")

ax.plot(df_hoy["Hora"], df_hoy["high1"], linestyle = "--", color = "g")

ax.plot(df_hoy["Hora"], df_hoy["low2"], linestyle = "--", color = "y") 

ax.plot(df_hoy["Hora"], df_hoy["high2"], linestyle = "--", color = "y")

ax.plot(df_hoy["Hora"], df_hoy["low3"], linestyle = "--", color = "r")

ax.plot(df_hoy["Hora"], df_hoy["high3"], linestyle = "--", color = "r")

fig.set_size_inches([30,8])

plt.xticks(rotation=45)

ax.set_xlabel('Hora', size = 14)

ax.set_ylabel('Precio Dolar', size = 14)

plt.savefig("Evolucion-Dolar.jpg")

plt.show()



df.to_csv("tipo_cambio.csv", index= False)
pyscript.write("grafico",plt.show())
```

Comment: Coloca el código HTML del formulario para ayudarte mejor

Comment: @ElFuturo-Llego si el código es de Python (o de cualquier lenguaje donde la identación es crítica), _no toques el código_: solo OP puede hacerlo. Primero preguntá si es que efectivamente el código es así o fue un error al _copypastear_ nada más. Si fue lo segundo, de todas maneras, OP debe editarlo.

Comment: acabo de subir el HTML, el codigo de python me lo paso un compañero de trabajo preguntandome si lograba subirlo a una pagina web y que solo visualizara el grafico, yo creyendo que seria sencillo acepte y llevo 4 dias estancado probando de todo.

Comment: Tu idea es hacer una especie de pagina web donde los usuarios capturen los datos? o simplemente una especie de aplicación donde un usuario lo capture de manera local?

Comment: es una pagina web donde ingresas los datos al formulario y estos puedan pasarse al grafico, es de manera local.